# my canvas is not showing up in the browser

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

for some reason my html5 canvas is not showing up in the browser.
I am trying to draw a black square its just not loading the browser is just an empty page...
Please help me i dont know whats wrong..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>setup</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas
var canvasContext
window.onload = function() {
canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d")
canvasContext.fillStyle = "black";
canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
canvasContext.fillStyle = "red";
canvasContext.fillRect(125, 250, 75, 75)
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your canvas is `id="canvas"` but your selector is looking for `myCanvas`. Also, if you run a script and it doesn't do what you expect, please open your developer console and look at the error. It pretty much tells you exactly what the problem is and lets you solve the problem much more quickly than posting here.

Answer (score 1):

Your canvas 'is' there - it's just a white (empty) blob however.

None of your interactions with it work as you've tried to find it using the ID "myCanvas" rather than just "canvas" which is the ID you used in your HTML.

If you change this line:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
```

to

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
```

It should work for you

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for the question:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.